# Grails action issure

Tags: grails

*Hi all,*

I have some problem with grails.

`<g:form action="search"  method="post">`

`def search ={println('Hello')}`

I do not known why when i run it aways  tell me *"The requested resource (/User/user/search) is not available".*

But when i tried to edtit anything and then saved it have done. Then i shut down and run again it also tell *"The requested resource (/User/user/search) is not available".*

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more precise about your problem? Clear reproduction steps for the issue would help, as might do a longer code listing.

Comment: More information in the question will help. For example what are the names of the files each of those code snippets come from?

Answer (score 2):

So I think this is your issue:

When an Action in a Controller finishes it needs to know what to send back to the requesting web browser. There are 2 main ways to tell your app what (or where) to send the user.

**Redirect** - You use this to tell the app to send the user to a different part of your application, or to any URL. More info can be found here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html

**Render** - You can use this to tell your app to render some text as the response to the user. The main ways are to either specify the text directly e.g. `render "Hello"`, or you can tell it a template or view (GSPs) to use to render the content. Info: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

I think your problem is that if you do not use either of these in your action (and you haven't) then **the default behaviour is to render a view with the same name as your action**. So I think your app is trying to render a view at *user/search.gsp* which (I am guessing) doesn't exist.

So if you change your action to look like this:

```
def search = {
    println("Hello 1")
    render("Hello 2")
}
```

You should not have your error and you should see "Hello 2" returned to the user's web browser. Alternatively you could create the view called *search.gsp* in the *user/* directory and then that view will be used for what is returned to the user.